# Split up program with 2 dimensional arrays into Functions (C)

Tags: c, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I've written a program in C which allows me to move around in a "room" which is a 2 dimensional array. It works fine, but now I am running into issues when trying to split it up into functions. I might approach it completely wrong as I've only worked in Visual Basic, where stuff like this is much easier. 
The void functions with `printf` also work perfectly fine.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void instruction(void) {
        printf("Move: W=up, D=right, S=down, A=left an apply with RETURN.\n");
}
void wall(void) {
        printf("##### You are in front of a wall. Please move somewhere else! #####\n");
}
int runter(roomxy, y, x, index) {
        roomxy[y][x] = 0;
        y = y + 1;
        if (y>3 || y<0) {
                y = y - 1;
                wall();
                index--;
                return (index);
        }
        return (roomxy[y][x]);
}

void main() {
char c[2];
int steps;
int i;
int j;
int k;
int room[4][4] = { 0 };
int ypos = 0;
int xpos = 0;

room[ypos][xpos] = 1;
for(j=0; j<4; j++) {
        for(k=0; k<4; k++) {
                printf("%d ", room[j][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
}


printf("How many steps do you want to make? (Number from 1 to 50.)\n");
scanf("%d", &steps);
if (steps>0 && steps<51) {
                for (i=1; i<=steps; i++) {
                        instruction();
                        scanf("%s", c);
                        if (c[0] == 'S' || c[0] == 's') {
                                room = runter(room, ypos, xpos, i);
                                /*room[ypos][xpos] = 0;
                                ypos = ypos + 1;
                                if (ypos>3 || ypos<0) {
                                        ypos = ypos - 1;
                                        wall();
                                        i--;
                                }*/
                        }
                        else if (c[0] == 'W' || c[0] == 'w') {
                                room[ypos][xpos] = 0;
                                ypos = ypos - 1;
                                if (ypos>3 || ypos<0) {
                                        ypos = ypos + 1;
                                        wall();
                                        ypos = ypos + 1;
                                        wall();
                                        i--;
                                }
                        }
                        else if (c[0] == 'D' || c[0] == 'd') {
                                room[ypos][xpos] = 0;
                                xpos = xpos + 1;
                                if (xpos>3 || xpos<0) {
                                        xpos = xpos - 1;
                                        wall();
                                        i--;
                                }
                        }
                        else if (c[0] == 'A' || c[0] == 'a') {
                                room[ypos][xpos] = 0;
                                xpos = xpos - 1;
                                if (xpos>3 || xpos<0) {
                                        xpos = xpos + 1;
                                        wall();
                                        i--;
                                }
                        }
                        else {printf("##### ERROR: Only type in W, D, S or A! #####\n"); i--;}
                        room[ypos][xpos] = 1;
                        printf("Ihre Position:\n");
                        for(j=0; j<4; j++) {
                                for(k=0; k<4; k++) {
                                        printf("%d ", room[j][k]);
                                }
                                printf("\n");
                                                }
                }
}
else {printf("##### Please enter number from 1 to 50! #####\n");}
}
```

The error I am getting is "subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector".
I don't know how to move on as I am completely stuck at trying to figure out how functions with arrays work in C.
I've also read about the `typedef` argument, but I also don't really know how to work with it.

Obviously I am a bloody noob at programming in general.

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: That code compiles? The definition for `runter` is missing the datatypes for it's parameters

Comment: Your function prototype should be like this `int runter(int roomxy[], int y, int x, int index)`.

Comment: aren't these all declared as integer?
ok, I didn't know how to do that, I'll try, thanks!

Comment: You should put some efforts info formatting your code. It's for your own good.

Comment: Sorry, I am still a bloody beginner as I've only programmed small stuff in Visual Basic. What's the matter with my formatting?

Comment: Formatting can be a bit subjective, but there are commonly used patterns. The problem with your formatting is firstly the indentation. Sometimes you don't indent at all (like after `main() {`) and you have a wild `}` near the end (which is probably a just a typo). Indenting 8 characters (a full tabstop) in C is considered excessive. You can also make good use of spaces between certain lines of code (like between blocks). Do a search on "C formatting standards" and you'll find some good suggestions that will increase the readability of your C code.

Comment: What line of your code do you get your error message on? When a C compiler gives an error message, it usually gives you the line number. But generically, the message means you are dereferencing a value with an array subscript (using brackets: `[...]`) but the identifier you applied the brackets to is not an array, nor a pointer, nor a vector, which are the only valid types you can treat as an array. I'm sure Visual Basic would have similar restrictions on what you can treat as an array.

Comment: The problem is likely here: `int runter(roomxy, y, x, index) {
        roomxy[y][x] = 0; ....` You neglected to declare the types of the arguments for `runter`, so C may have assumed `int`. And `roomxy[y][x]` would then try to treat a simple `int` as an array. You might have seen some compiler warnings. If so, you should heed them.

Comment: You have posted too much code. Most of the stuff is not relevant to your question. Please create [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for all those answers. This program is part of my apprenticeship, and I have to do it in vocational school. I don't learn that kind of stuff and we're just thrown into vim and have to program some stuff.
That's why your tips are really useful!

Answer (score 1):

Your source code is muddled, so there are a number of things to fix.

First, change `void main()` to `int main(void)`. That is just required by the C standard; `main` must be either `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` in normal situations.

Next, you must declare parameter types when you declare a function. `int runter(roomxy, y, x, index)` is wrong because it fails to say what types the parameters are. Likely, you want either `int runter(int roomxy[][4], int y, int x, int index)` or `int runter(int *roomxy, int y, int x, int index)`. The former passes the entire array (by way of a pointer to its first subarray) to `runter`. The latter passes a pointer to a specific element. The first should be used if `runter` needs to work with multiple elements of the array. The second should be used if `runter` needs to work with only a specific element. However, using the second form requires additional changes in your program, and it requires use of pointers that you may not have learned about yet, so I am going to omit discussion of that.

Then, it is not clear what you want `runter` to return. In one place inside the function, you have `return (index);`. In another, you have `return (roomxy[[y][x]);`. It is not clear to me whether the `index` and `roomxy[y][x]` are two possible values of one kind of thing you want to return or whether they are different kinds of things. If they are the same kind of thing, okay. But if they represent different things, it generally does not make sense for a function to return one or the other.

In any case, `return` statements do not need parentheses. `return index;` and `return roomxy[y][x]` are fine.

Where you call `runter`, you have `room = runter(room, ypos, xpos, i);`. This does not make sense because `room` is an array but `runter` returns an `int`. You cannot assign an `int` to an array. Perhaps you meant `room[ypos][xpos] = runter(room, ypos, xpos, 1);`. (If so, then it does appear you want `runter` to work with a single element, so the pointer-to-an-element solution would be better. But you can get the program working and then worry about that.)

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out sometime in the future. I will give you an answer when I have some time on my hands :)

Answer (score -2):

I have modified your source. in runter() you are returning int and have catch with room which is pointer(2 dimensional). it's impossible.
Add on to this you should have declare datatype in int runter(roomxy, y, x, index). I have corrected it.

```
                #include <stdio.h>
    void instruction(void) {
            printf("Move: W=up, D=right, S=down, A=left an apply with RETURN.\n");
    }
    void wall(void) {
            printf("##### You are in front of a wall. Please move somewhere else! #####\n");
    }
    void runter(int roomxy[][4], int y, int x, int index) {
            roomxy[y][x] = 0;
            y = y + 1;
            if (y>3 || y<0) {
                    y = y - 1;
                    wall();
                    index--;
        //            return (index);
            }
          //  return (roomxy[y][x]);
    }

    int main() {
    char c[2];
    int steps;
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    int room[4][4] = { 0 };
    int ypos = 0;
    int xpos = 0;

    room[ypos][xpos] = 1;
    for(j=0; j<4; j++) {
            for(k=0; k<4; k++) {
                    printf("%d ", room[j][k]);
            }
            printf("\n");
    }


    printf("How many steps do you want to make? (Number from 1 to 50.)\n");
    scanf("%d", &steps);
    if (steps>0 && steps<51) {
                    for (i=1; i<=steps; i++) {                                    
                            instruction();
                            scanf("%s", c);
                            if (c[0] == 'S' || c[0] == 's') {                               
    /*                                room[ypos][xpos] = */runter(room, ypos, xpos, i);
                                    room[ypos][xpos] = 0;  
                                    ypos = ypos + 1;
                                    if (ypos>3 || ypos<0) {
                                            ypos = ypos - 1;
                                            wall();
                                            i--;
                                    }
                            }        
                            else if (c[0] == 'W' || c[0] == 'w') {
                                    room[ypos][xpos] = 0;
                                    ypos = ypos - 1;
                                    if (ypos>3 || ypos<0) {
                                            ypos = ypos + 1;
                                            wall();
    /*                                        ypos = ypos + 1;
                                            wall();*/
                                            i--;
                                    }
                            }
                            else if (c[0] == 'D' || c[0] == 'd') {
                                    room[ypos][xpos] = 0;
                                    xpos = xpos + 1;
                                    if (xpos>3 || xpos<0) {
                                            xpos = xpos - 1;
                                            wall();
                                            i--;
                                    }
                            }
                            else if (c[0] == 'A' || c[0] == 'a') {
                                    room[ypos][xpos] = 0;
                                    xpos = xpos - 1;
                                    if (xpos>3 || xpos<0) {                
                                            xpos = xpos + 1;
                                            wall();
                                            i--;                                  
                                    }     
                            }              
                            else {printf("##### ERROR: Only type in W, D, S or A! #####\n"); i--;}
                            room[ypos][xpos] = 1;                                      
                            printf("Ihre Position:\n");    
                            for(j=0; j<4; j++) {    
                                    for(k=0; k<4; k++) {   
                                            printf("%d ", room[j][k]);
                                    }              
                                    printf("\n");
                                                    }
                    }                
    }                                                             
    else {printf("##### Please enter number from 1 to 50! #####\n");}

    return 0;                                              
    }
```

Comment: This is incorrect: `runter((int **)room, ypos, xpos, i)`. You cannot cast `int[4][4]` to  `int**` and expect it to work. Those are 2 entirely different data types.

Comment: Also, don't repost complete source code on answer. Only post the relevant lines, and explain the changes.

Comment: Thank you! It's compiling now, but at the part where I am entering the movement, it aborts with "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

Comment: @J.W. I have corrected your runter() function to return nothing with void. I think it doesn't need to return things. it works now